# Count 'Number of Transactions'

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services, count, ssrs-2008

I'm trying to get a count of *'number of transactions'* that occurred'. 
The data could look like this.

```
Cust #   Trans#  TransType  LineItem
42        5000      1         1
42        6000      1         1
42        6000      1         2
42        6000      2         1
42        6000      2         2
42        6000      2         3
```

There can be multiple transaction types for any given transaction number. In this example, my desired returned 'number of transactions' count is '3', as Trans# 5000 only had one different TransType and 6000 had two. If I do a distinct count of Trans# I get '2' and if I do just a count, I get '6'.

I've tried working with:

```
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE Trans# WHEN ???? THEN 1 ELSE null END) AS [Num of Transactions],
```

But I know that I'm not quite on the right track. If anyone could point me in the right direction, it'd be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :-

```
with cte as
(
  Select Cust,Trans,row_number() over (partition by trans,TransType order by cust) rn
  from Sample
)
Select count(*) as TransCount from cte
where rn=1
```

[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1dd84/3) DEMO

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm new to SQL so this answer forced me to go lookup and understand WITH and OVER :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following to get the count of distinct transtype for each customer and transaction:

```
select cust,
  trans,
  count(distinct transtype) cnt
from yourtable
group by cust, trans;
```

Then if you want a total of that count, you can apply `sum()` to the query:

```
select sum(cnt) Total
from
(
  select cust,
    trans,
    count(distinct transtype) cnt
  from yourtable
  group by cust, trans
) src
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c2a48/5) of both queries.